# Display Firebase Database last child, first in RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am storing some data in firebase and retrieving it in firebase RecyclerView.
data is been displayed fine but I want to display data from bottom to top in myrecyclerview because latest added child will be added in the bottom and I wanted to show latest added child in top of myrecyclerview.

I tried `myrecyclerview.setReverseLayout(true);` but this is taking me to the bottom of my activity where first child is available. rather I want to show my latest child when activity is opened.

Answer (score 2):

**setStackFromEnd=true** and **setReverseLayout=true**

The difference between these two is that `setStackFromEnd` will set the view to show the last element, the layout direction will remain the same whereas `setReverseLayout` will change the order of the elements added by the Adapter.
In your case, use this

```
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
```

but don't use this

```
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

Something like this:

```
mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mLinearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
//mLinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
yourRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
```

Comment: I am using `layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);` only

Comment: its StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Comment: Can you try it with Linear layout Manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

Add the `getItem(int position)` method to your `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` as:

```
@Override
public ItemClass getItem(int position) {
    return super.getItem(getCount() - position - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing that question is not checked as a correct answer.

Here is what you should do :

When add data to your **ArrayList** set an index, and second thing to add **notifyItemInserted** with index position.

Here is a complete code :

```
 val news = ArrayList<Book>()
            for (convSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                val conv = convSnapshot.getValue(Book::class.java)
                news.add(0, conv!!) // here we add index for ArrayList
            }
            val adapter = BooksListAdapter(news)
            mBooksListRecyclerView!!.adapter = adapter
            adapter.notifyItemInserted(0) // here we notifyItemInserted
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it worked for me

```
LinearLayoutManger myLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManger(this);

myLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
myLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(myLayoutManager);
```